# facet.range.other not working in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm using Apache Solr 4.6.
I do have this piece of code:

```
query.addNumericRangeFacet( SearchCriteriaUtils.AGE_FN, 20, 60, 10 );
query.add("f."+SearchCriteriaUtils.AGE_FN+".facet.range.other", "before");
query.add("f."+SearchCriteriaUtils.AGE_FN+".facet.range.other", "after");
```

Also I could confirm the piece of query in solr console:

```
facet=true&f.hdrAge.facet.range.end=60&facet.mincount=1&f.hdrAge.facet.range.start=20&f.hdrAge.facet.range.other=before&f.hdrAge.facet.range.other=after&facet.limit=25&facet.range=hdrAge&f.hdrAge.facet.range.gap=10
```

I am 100% positive that there are records with age values lower than 20 and greater than 60.
Even so, I still get ONLY 4 counts for 20, 30, 40, and 50 respectively.

Am I missing something or this is a bug in Solr?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:
I need to use RangeFacet.getBefore() and RangeFacet.getAfter() to get those counts!